Why text is not moving to the top-right of the image?
My understanding is that both img and span are inline elements and should be moved next to each other.
However, I don't see that happening in below example.
Can someone please provide more details to clearly understand the concept here?
My HTML Body looks as below:
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mac.jpg" alt="Mountain landscape">
    <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid, non cumque, eveniet atque et
      suscipit quisquam libero saepe fugiat vero qui nulla labore tempore nostrum? Quisquam quibusdam illo
      tempora!</span>
  </div>
</body>


My CSS looks as below:
p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
img {
    width: 300px;
}



Aren’t they sharing the same baseline? In that sense next to each other.

Use flexbox to make child elements (img and span) side by side.


.container {
      display: flex;
    }

    img {
      width: 300px;
    }

    span {
      margin-left: 16px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
<div class="container">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mac.jpg" alt="Mountain landscape">
      <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aliquid, non cumque, eveniet atque et
        suscipit quisquam libero saepe fugiat vero qui nulla labore tempore nostrum? Quisquam quibusdam illo
        tempora!</span>
    </div>




This doesn’t answer the question which is “Why…”

I understand using flexbox it can be resolved but want to know why it is not working without flexbox.

Without using flexbox, it's not working as expected because of how block-level and inline elements behave, and how they interact inside a div (a block container).

@Mahesh Prajapati can you please provide more details to clearly understand the concept here?
